# Classification of the singularity of the following function $f(z)=e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Classification of the singularity of the following function

$f(z)=e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}$

So $e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}=e^ze^{\frac{1}{z}}$

So we have a singularity at $z=0$, how do I classify this?

I think I can neglect $e^z$ as it is an entire function

Ok so I have $f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ is known to be analytic on all of $\Bbb C /\{0\}$, then by Laurent's theorem I have

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$$ .

where

$$a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz$$

which in the particular case I was asking about would become

$$a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i } \int_{C(z_0,r)} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^{n}}dz$$

Can someone explain how I solve this to classify the singularity and does this tell me the order of the pole??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the sequence $z_n=n$ the function tends to $\infty$. Along the sequence $z_n=\frac i n$ we get $f(z_n)=e^{\frac i n+\frac  n i}=e^{-i(n-\frac   1n)}$ which has modulus $1$. These facts imply that $0$ is neither a pole nor a removable singularity. Hence  it is an essential singularity.

Comment: To confirm, that is the only singularity?

Comment: Of course. At any other point $f$ is a composition of differentiable functions hence it is differentiable.  @David